# how to create pagination using mysql and node js express web api note:im not using orm

Tags: mysql, node.js

Im trying to do pagination on mysql select * from  student result  here is my API once i fire the api again it returns the same reords returned on first call

i have done alot of research but most of  the examples use mongodb not mysql

```
router.get('/getPlanPeriods', auth.verifyToken,(req, res)=> {
    jwt.verify(req.token, secreteKey)
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM student limit=?,?',[req.query.limit,oquery.query.offse]  (err,rows,fields) =>
            {
                if(!err)
                 res.send(rows);
            });    


    });
```

Comment: Syntax - change 'limit=?,?' to 'limit ?,?'. Is `oquery.query.offse` a typo?

Comment: sorry typing mistake its  [req.query.limit,req.query.offset] these are the two query string parameter and the limit ?,?

Comment: Your query seems fine. Refer https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp

Comment: Mark it as answered or closed if resolved.